# How to use raw_input in a socket

Tags: python, sockets, input, tcp

Just before I say anything, if you are confused about the title it means to say I used this bit of code: `cmd, addr = sock.accept()` how could I use that code for the clients to see the raw_input, Here's my code:

```
from socket import *

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
HOST = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 8080
sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
sock.listen(5)

while True:
    cmd, addr = sock.accept()
    cmd.send ('Welcome to server.py\r\n')
    main = raw_input("> ")
```

Here is my output:

-bash-4.1# python server.py

>

i want that to be on the client side when they connect that's there but its on the server side

Comment: `cmd.send(raw_input(">"))` ?

Comment: @joran-beasley ^ that might work but i need it so i can declare what its called like main

Comment: `cmd.send(main)` then I guess... its not clear what your question actually is ...

Comment: @joran-beasley i just edited my post

Comment: If you want that on the client side, the application on the client side should display it. Not the server.

Comment: Thing is its coming up on the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Converting my comment to an answer]

There are two applications here (possibly on two different machines). One application opens a server socket and listens for the connection. Upon a connection from another process (client), it sends the string `Welcome to server ...` .

The second application creates a client socket and connects to the server. Once connection is established the two processes can *talk* to each other using such strings (this is slightly inaccurate, but is okay for this answer). It is then the job of the two processes to co-ordinate with each other using whatever they have received from the other side.

> i want that to be on the client side when they connect that's there but its on the server side
>
> Thing is its coming up on the server side

What you need to do is change your **client process** (the one can connects to the server) -- **NOT the script you have posted** -- the other process, to have `raw_input(..)`.

Comment: I don't connect to the server with a client.py lol i use putty and connect with RAW

Comment: In that case, just do: `cmd.send("> ")`

Comment: will cmd.send(""> ) let me type things in instead of it just printing text?

Comment: I have never used Putty (or Putty in raw mode). I am just assuming it is a telnet equivalent. `cmd.send("> ")` will just print the text within Putty. The Putty, on the other hand, is **always** ready to accept keyboard input. This, in a way, would give you an *illusion* of the prompt on Putty.

Comment: Well anyhow that second reply of cmd.send(">") worked